# Can't import a package from a different file in GO

Tags: go, go-modules

I am using `go1.13.4` and below is my project structure:

```
src/types/type.go
src/utils/util.go
go.mod
```

In go.mod:

```
module example.com/graphql

go 1.13

require github.com/graph-gophers/graphql-go v0.0.0-20191031232829-adde0d0f76a3
```

In src/types/type.go:

```
package types

type USER struct {
   ...
}
```

In src/utils/util.go,

```
package utils
import (
    "example.com/graphql/types"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)
```

I got tan error when build the project:

```
$ go build ./...
src/utils/utils.go:4:2: cannot find module providing package example.com/graphql/types
```

I wonder why it can't find the package `example.com/graphql/types`? I am reading https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules and I already set the module name in `go.mod` file at the root of my project.

Comment: Please see [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) (particularly the sections on import paths and your first library) and [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html) (particularly the section on names).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your current layout, import path of `types` is `example.com/graphql/src/types`.

`go.mod` should be inside `src` if you have that structure. Or better would be to get rid of `src`. `go.mod` must be next to the `types` and `utils` folders.